# TLS1.2 Decrypting "Finished" message

Tags: ssl, encryption, aes, tls1.2

I am implementing simplified version of TLS1.2 server socket, and I have troubles decrypting clients "Finished" message. I have successfully exchanged messages up to clients "Finished" message. I have computed master_secret correctly(master_secret extracted from browser matches one computed by me), expanded material for keys but I have no luck decrypting clients message. Here is what have I exactly done:

Exchanged messages with following important result:

```
cipher_suite = "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA"
master_secret = "bee102cfec022435774e97a9718628798643563b2e95626dc405f20660e023b6da73846bf54879bc53780760535316fd"
client_random = "99ab80aa2659df3ddb367f0d1e65b121d87782e26f7d75a7121c763833138529"
server_random = "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
```

Based on above I have generated following key material:

```
key_client_write = "64288957f9ad56be81db1af6a00f49713bd1fc7e89a56093fc8d18a9efe62267"
key_server_write = "280b12c845df613e5bc62f92337e6cbb91fcba5a63df535c77d06d16b5ef85ce"
```

But no luck decrypting following "Finished" message sent by client(Firefox browser), I separated record layer header by a single space from encrypted part:

```
client_finished = "1603030040 b5d75b9c79a08d3895ae4e623187078e099c9af49ec5dcd65bfe31c11b0a404689b75d4bf73aabb74c947449adf52c15d01f541dbccf83c14ef8cdbfaeef94d3"
```

I am treating data as follows:

```
iv = "b5d75b9c79a08d3895ae4e623187078e"
ciphertext = "099c9af49ec5dcd65bfe31c11b0a404689b75d4bf73aabb74c947449adf52c15d01f541dbccf83c14ef8cdbfaeef94d37ffbbbdfe042200e2db7"
```

Tried to use both keys but decrypted messages does not make any sense.

Are my keys wrong or, am I interpreting data wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was interpreting key_material in a wrong way. I took 32 bytes for MAC key, but it should be 20 bytes.